# ESP8266 Wifi Module - prints "ready" but not responding to AT commands

Tags: arduino, wifi, at-command, esp8266

Just received my first ESP8266 wifi module with some excitement. However I've been unable to fully communicate with it. I have connected the module to my computer via a usb to serial cable and I'm power the module via a separate power supply (3.3v).

After powering the module up I receive the following information (via PuTTY or and Arduino serial monitor window):

```
[Vendor:www.ai-thinker.com Version:0.9.2.4]

ready
```

I have tried sending various AT commands e.g.

```
AT+RST
```

But I get no response. Using ctrl+m and ctrl+j in putty didn't help either.

Please see my youtube video if its helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvasOuHuWDc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you have putty or the Arduino serial console configured to send both a newline `\n` and a carriage return `\r` character. So AT+RST actually ends up being `AT+RST\r\n`. This took me a bit when I first received my ESP8266 modules. On the Arduino serial console this option is at the bottom of the window. I can see in your video you have it set to no line ending. Hopefully that does it for you.

Comment: Keith, thank you so much for this. I had it working within 2 minutes of waking up and seeing your message :)  Still not sure how to configure PuTTY, but at least I have something to work with :)

Answer (score 12):

To get AT OK .

1.AT + PRESS ENTER + THEN CTRL +J WILL GIVE OK

2.Then Enter commands to execute

eg AT+GMR ->presss enter then ctrl+j 
to get firmware
repeat step 1 for each command.